# Add a title or description to an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

If you open an app like gmail, and you compose a new email in the To and Subject lines, it says To and Subject in the respective `EditText`'s. How do you add a title like that to an `EditText`? Are those custom views? Or is it possible to do that with the default widget?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called a `hint`. 
Set your hint [programatically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) or use it as [xml attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint).

Answer (score 6):

I think the attribute [`hint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some sample code:

```
<EditText android:hint="Write Caption" />
```